# Chrome delay loading cached SVG file

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, svg, browser-cache, cache-control

I have javascript code that requests an SVG resource file for displaying.

The SVG won't change. It is about 100kb, containing one embedded jpeg image (as a `data:image/jpeg:base64`). So I'd like the browser to cache it if possible.

The code to load the svg is something like this

```
$(btn).click(function(){
    console.log("loading...");
    $(element).load("mri/t1/axi/t1_axi_100.svg", function(resp, status, xhr){
       console.log("loaded");
       ...
    });
});
```

It seems this takes 2 seconds. All of this time delay is in between the "loading..." and "loaded". You can see from the profiling (chrome dev tools timeline), that there's no processing going on in between: the left call stack is for the "click" event, and the right one is for the "loaded" handler. In between is a gap where "mri/t1/axi/t1_axi_100.svg" is allegedly loading (long blue bar near top).

[image]

However when I look in Network under chrome dev tools, I see that each of the "download" steps took < 4 ms only. (narrow blue bars on right hand side; note the large gaps)

[image]

You can also see here that the caching has worked (svgs from disk cache; embedded jpegs from memory cache).

The breakdown of the 4ms for the svg is shown here.
[image]

So why is there a 2 second delay? My code takes 4 ms, and the retrieval from the cache seems to take 4 ms!

The headers shown in the "Network" tab are:

```
General
  Request URL:http://homphysiology.org/neurosim/basic/slices/mri/t1/axi/t1_axi_100.svg
  Request Method:GET
  Status Code:200 OK (from disk cache)
  Remote Address:173.254.28.84:80

Response Headers
  Accept-Ranges:bytes
  Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
  Content-Encoding:gzip
  Content-Type:image/svg+xml
  Date:Tue, 17 Jan 2017 15:49:02 GMT
  Expires:Thu, 16 Feb 2017 15:49:02 GMT
  Last-Modified:Thu, 11 Aug 2016 18:26:42 GMT
  Server:nginx/1.10.2
  Vary:Accept-Encoding
  X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
Request Headers
  Provisional headers are shown
  Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
  Referer:http://homphysiology.org/neurosim/basic/case2_nonlinear.html
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
  X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Could Chrome be polling the server and waiting for a response? 
If so can I prevent this? Alternatively could it be that the XHR ready state is not being triggered in a timely fashion?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like server delay to me.

You show us two different resource downloads at Timeline and Network tabs. First one is `t1_axi_100.svg` and second one is `t1_axi_070.svg`. Probably browser took only `t1_axi_070.svg` from cache. [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte) for `t1_axi_100.svg` was 1.75 seconds in my case.

Comment: Right, yes, but I guess the point is, I want both to be taken from the cache. The steps I've mentioned in the question are supposed to illustrate how I've tried to coax Chrome into taking the svg files from the cache, but that seems to be failing? Thanks

Comment: Please show the HTTP headers of SVG request and response that browser doesn't cache. Use Chrome DevTools [Copy All as HAR](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy).